# Chartjs Data via json request not populating

Tags: php, json, ajax, chart.js

I'm using PHP and SQL to produce an array which counts data with the same values and how many of those value there are which outputs a json_encode to:

`{"05":4,"09":4,"19":4}`

**Chart.js file: (trimmed down)**

```
// Chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("monthAbuseChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Offences",
        //data: [0, 7, 5] This works
        data: offences // This doesn't
    }],
  }
  }
});
// Grab the data for offences:
var offences = []

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "sql/monthabuse.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (result) {

      //offences = result;
        var offences = result;
        console.log(result);
    },
  });
```

The console.log outputs `{19: 4, 05: 4, 09: 4}`

However, if I put offences into the data section `data: offences` it doesn't work?

Comment: I don't catch it. Are you creating chart before getting the data? And... can you explain better this `However, if I put console.log(offences) it outputs the same.`
What do you expect? you are saying offenses = result... Can you reword your question so i can help you?

Comment: @Pipe I've tried to reword it to make sense, basically, the console.log(offences) shows it as {19: 4, 05: 4, 09: 4}, however, when I try and put it in my chart section for data (As per my comments in the script), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to populate the response of `AJAX` Call in `offences` variable. 
There are 2 issues with your current code:

1. Your code to create chart is running before the AJAX Call has run. In your code you are referencing `offences` variable but it is not yet populated.
2. You have defined `offences` as a global Variable, which is ok. But inside the AJAX Call you are again defining a new Local Variable `offences` by prefixing it with `var`. You need to use the below code which is commented in your question to populate the Global `offences` var.

```
    offences = result
```

One way of fixing this would be to encompass your Chart Code in a New Function and inside the success callback of AJAX, call this New Function.

```
//Global Variable
var offences = [];

function createMonthAbuseChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("monthAbuseChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3"],
          datasets: [{
            label: "Offences",
            //data: [0, 7, 5] This works
            data: offences // This doesn't
        }],
      }
      }
    });
}

// Grab the data for offences:
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "sql/monthabuse.php",
  dataType : 'json',
  success: function (result) {
      offences = result;
      console.log(result);
      createMonthAbuseChart(); //Call the Chart Create Method Here.
  },
});
```

You must make sure that data returned by AJAX Call has the same format as the data required for chart which is `[0, 7, 5]`. From your question it looks your AJAX Call is returning `{19: 4, 05: 4, 09: 4}`. You can use the following code to convert it into  `[4, 4, 4]`

```
    offences = Object.values(result);
```

Use the above line instead of following in your AJAX Callback

```
    offences = result;
```

Comment: Works perfectly and a great explanation, thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)